# Cancel paypal recuring payments with ExpressCheckout

Tags: php, paypal, payment, recurring

I'm creating an website where you have to pay 1 dollar/month to use an account. Ok, it is working, but the person who uses it can access paypal website and cancel the recurring payment, but still use the account. 
How can I solve it?
The codes that I'm using: https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to setup [Instant Payment Notification (IPN)](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/) to handle that.

Any time any transaction hits your PayPal account (whether it's a payment, a new subscription, a failed payment, a suspended profile, a refund, a customer dispute, etc.) the PayPal server will POST data about that transaction to a script you have sitting on your server.

Your script can receive that data and process it however you need to, so in this case you would get an IPN with a txn_type=recurring_payment_profile_cancel.  Based on that, you could then update your own database to show their account is canceled and then not allow them to login.

Alternatively, you could use the [GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails_API_Operation_NVP/) API to check the current status of the profile each time somebody logs in to your app, and if it's not Active, react accordingly.

Comment: Do I need to create a column called PayerIdPaypal for all users?

Comment: Another way is (using sandbox for example): I can see when someone cancel a recurring payment. Then, if I have the payerID on my database, I can see what is the name of the people who canceled and delete his account. Right?

Comment: Oh no, the payerId (example: YYYYYYYYYYYYY) is not equal Profile Id (example: I-XXXXXXXXXXXX)

Comment: The Payer ID is simply PayPal's ID for the account holder.  The Profile ID is what you want to be checking to see if it's active.

Comment: I did `if ($_POST['tnx_type'] == "subscr_failed") { //insert something on database to test }` but doesnt work...

Comment: subscr_failed is for standard subscriptions, not the recurring payments API.  Check the [IPN variable list](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id08CTB0S055Z) under the Transaction Types section, and you'll see a bunch of that start with recurring_payment_.  Those are what you want.